# Header syntax does not start newline after mainPanel

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to learn how to create R Markdown documents containing Shiny elements.

I ended up having a problem that header syntax `##` does not create a new line before the header, instead, the header is shown right to the previous `mainPanel` element. Below is shown the resulting image:

[image]

and here is code which generates the situation:

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))

output$plot <- renderPlot({
  plot(pressure)
})
```

## Next header

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

What should I do in order to ensure that the header starts with a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mainPanel()` is not meant to be on its own. If you look at the documentation, it's meant to be created inside a `sidebarLayout()`, where the layout will take care of itself.

The correct thing to do here would be to simply remove `mainPanel()` from your code, and that would fix the issue. If you used it because you want the plot to not take up the entire width, you can use the `width` Rmd chunk option for that.

Another solution that I don't recommend but would also work if you really do want a panel is to complete the panels properly by creating a full `sidebarLayout()`:

```
sidebarLayout(
  mainPanel = mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")),
  sidebarPanel = "",
  position = "right"
)
```

Comment: The use of `sidebarLayout()` indeed explains why `mainPanel()` does not result into a newline.